# What's the difference between じゃあね and またね?

Tags: words, phrases, spoken-language, greetings

My teacher told me years ago about またね, but recently I've heard じゃあね used similarly. What's the difference between じゃあね and またね?  Which one is preferable?

Is there other phrases, that can be used to say "goodbye / see you later"? Maybe from dialects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

また means "again", and じゃあ means something like "so", "okay", or "then". Thus, またね is closer to "see you again" or "see you next time", whereas じゃあね is just "bye". But またね is used fairly casually, and it's usually *not* a serious promise/suggestion to meet you again. You can also say じゃあまたね.